# htaccess rewrite to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

Building a web application I'm using relative paths like:

```
<img src="/assets/images/image.png" />
```

or

```
<script src="/build/app.min.js"></script>
```

from within a `index.html` file inside subfolders.

The directory structure is:

```
root
  .htaccess
  - subdir1
     - index.html
  - subdir2
     - index.html
```

the problem is that both `index.html` files use relative paths and they have to be served with a `RewriteRule`.

The `.htacess` looks like:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ subdir1/assets/$1 [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^build/(.*)$ subdir1/build/$1 [L,NC]

</ifModule>
```

Of course it does work only for `subdir1` but not for `subdir2`.

How can I serve resources to both subfolders to keep using relative paths?

Am I missing something?

Comment: With the same url for subdir1 and subdir2 ?

Comment: Why not use relative paths i.e. `<img src="assets/images/image.png" />`

Comment: because it would be a problem for other enviroments; using backbone routing and I should change the `root` for the `routes` to differentiate between dev and production environment for saying one. 
I don't want to find myself in a situation where I have to use `../../` to load resources.